# Microstrip directional coupler length = 90 degrees?

Tags: qucs

Desire to design a -30 db microstrip directional coupler using QUCS. Does the length of the coupled section of line need to be 90 degrees or will a shorter length of coupled line work? If I enter 45 degrees as the "angle" input on the QUCS and execute the " Synthesize" function will the resultant "W", "S" and "L" physical parameters QUCS produces provide me accurate design dimensions for the substrate parameters, Zoe and Zoo and frequency parameters I've input?

I'm trying to design a backward wave 30 db microstrip directional coupler. operating at 146.0 MHz with a Zo of 50 ohms. Using 0.062" FR-4. required a coupled length (90 degrees) of 10.68". The question is, can I get away with making the coupled length, say 45 degrees (5.34") and retain the Zo = 50 ohms impedance at all four ports? I suspect the coupling would wind up something greater than the desired 30 db at 146.0 MHz

Comment: not quite sure what kind of directional coupler you're referring to. Generally, lengths in microwave design are paramount, so my guess is that things are not randomly 45° long in phase.

Answer (score 1):

A single stage coupled line directional coupler will only work correctly at the frequency for which it's 90 degrees long. It will also work fairly well over +/- 10% frequency from that.

For -30 dB coupling, you barely need any 'design' at all. Two 50 Ω lines a long way apart will give you very loose coupling, adjust the spacing to get -30 dB, and the match will barely change, less than for any practical manufacturing tolerances anyway. It's for tight coupling, or wideband multistage designs, that you need proper design.

I've not used QUCS in the last decade, but it sounds like you're in a good position to experiment with it. Not sure why you would want to drive it any other way than the obvious way though, just tell it what 90 degrees is.

[edit] The reason for your desire for 45 degrees is that 90 degrees is 'too long' for your application.

You can make a coupler of some sorts with a 45 degree length. Port match will be the least of your problems. Directivity will be bad, and frequency response will be appalling.

Frequency response will be maximum output at the frequency where the coupler hits 90 degrees, the second harmonic of your wanted 146 MHz. If you adjust the coupling to give you -30dB at 146 MHz, you'll get rather more signal at 300 MHz. If you are treating the pickoff signal in a frequency selective way, this may not matter except for losing some dynamic range. However if you are only power detecting, and your source is a very efficient transmitter with a strong 2nd harmonic output, your power measurement will be way off.

At the low frequency of 146 MHz, it's straightforward to make a lumped component coupler which will have the directivity, and be a lot smaller. It will have much the same performance and narrow bandwidth as a transmission line λ/4 coupler, but be a lumped analogue of a quadrature hybrid but with unequal line impedances. If QUCS won't synthesise that for you, I'm sure you'll be able to find design resources on the net.

This is where we need more information than you've given in the question. For instance, if your application is power levelling a large transmitter, then insertion loss will be a key specification, and you may want to use real transmission line for the forward arm. There's no reason you shouldn't create a hybrid with λ/4 lengths of coax (folded, for physical length), cross coupled with lumped components. If you want to stay in microstrip, you could fold the transmission lines for length, at the expense of board area. There are lots of ways to skin this cat, but you need the other unspoken considerations to pick the best one.[/edit]

Comment: I'm trying to design a backward wave 30 db microstrip directional coupler. operating at 146.0 MHz with a Zo of 50 ohms.  Using 0.062" FR-4. required a coupled length (90 degrees) of 10.68".  The question is, can I get away with making the coupled length, say 45 degrees (5.34") and retain the Zo = 50 ohms impedance at all four ports?  I suspect the coupling would wind up something greater than the desired 30 db at 146.0 MHz

Comment: @woffermom see updates